# Wordpress: Cash on Delivery restrict to one country only

Tags: wordpress

I am selling products to 4 countries; US, Canada, UK and France. I have enabled 2 checkout methods; Cash on Delivery (cod) and Paypal. I want to restrict cod to Canada only and hide from other countries. I have tried the below code but it makes cod disappear from all countries (including Canada).I know i am doing something wrong here, i am not an expert so need ur help. Thanks

```
    /**
* @snippet       WooCommerce Disable Payment Gateway for a Specific Country
 */

function payment_gateway_disable_country( $available_gateways ) {
global $woocommerce;
if ( isset( $available_gateways['cod'] ) && $woocommerce->customer->get_country() <> 'France' ) {
unset( $available_gateways['cod'] );
} else if ( isset( $available_gateways['cod'] ) && $woocommerce->customer->get_country() == 'France' ) {
unset( $available_gateways['cod'] );
}
return $available_gateways;
}

add_filter( 'woocommerce_available_payment_gateways', 'payment_gateway_disable_country' );
```

Answer (score 2):

This should do it.

```
function payment_gateway_disable_country( $available_gateways ) {
    global $woocommerce;
    if ( isset( $available_gateways['cod'] ) && $woocommerce->customer->get_country() <> 'Canada' ) {
        unset( $available_gateways['cod'] );
    }
    return $available_gateways;
}

add_filter( 'woocommerce_available_payment_gateways', 'payment_gateway_disable_country' );
```